# Someone has already added that SSH key

Tags: bitbucket

Although no SSH keys are configured in my Bitbucket account, I get this error:

```
Someone has already added that SSH key.
```

I copied the SSH key pair from my previous machine to this machine. Probably this has something to do with this. Unfortunately, I did a factory reset on my previous machine so there's no way to "logout / remove the key" if this would be necessary.

Running `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` gives me:

```bash
authenticated via ssh key.
You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is this your second bitbucket account? Because it seems some account still has that key since you can authenticate with it.

Comment: Exactly. I'd like to use this key for 2 different Bitbucket accounts.

Comment: You can create a different public key and reuse your private key,

Comment: @LinFelix how? I can't find any docs on how to generate a second, different public key given an existing private key

Comment: @Gillespie use `-f <private key file>` e.g. https://serverfault.com/questions/52285/create-a-public-ssh-key-from-the-private-key

Comment: @LinFelix that just generates the same public key you already have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by using 2 different SSH pairs. One for each account. Source: https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/different-ssh-keys-multiple-bitbucket-accounts/

Comment: It appears Bitbucket searches ALL Bitbucket accounts for each key. The error message is unhelpful since it does not indicate this scope at all and users reasonably find themselves searching the list in context. It also seems like just a bad practice to entangle account concerns like this.